# Why the white spaces are ignored when converting to encrypted message?

Tags: c++

The Program should print the expected messages as expected but its not printing.

Plain Text message: **Hello! how are you?**

Expected encrypted message: **Glqqv! bvc Rfl avm?**

The program is printing: **Glqqv!bvcRflavm**

White spaces are totally ignored. How to fix it?

**The Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string alphabet {"!A2BCDEFGHIJ@KLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"};
    string key {"!X2ZNLWEBGJHQDYVTK2F#UOMPCIASRxznlwebgjhqdyvtkfuompciasr"};

    string secret_message{};
    string encrypted_message{};

    cout << "Enter your secret message: ";
    getline(cin, secret_message);

    cout << "'nEncrypting message.... ";

    for (char c: secret_message)
    {
        float position = alphabet.find(c);
        if(position != string::npos)
        {
            char new_char {key.at(position)};
            encrypted_message += new_char;
        }
    }
    cout << "\n Encrypted message is: "<< encrypted_message << '\n';
    cout << "\n\n" << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see no space character in your "alphabet".  The program is doing exactly as you've written.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie This should not be important to add spaces in alphabet I think, already getting the full input by getline(cin, secret_message);

Comment: Why do you use a `float` for the position? `find` returns an integer.

Comment: Follow the logic of your code, one statement at a time, when it finds  space.

Comment: @IndianaJones You're only adding a character if you can find it in your alphabet, and spaces are not in there, so you're skipping spaces and not including them in the final result.

Comment: @IndianaJones -- Put a `?` in your input.  You won't see a `?` in the output for the same reason you don't see a space.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel Exactly the float was a problem

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie well how to write them with spaces if it is possible?

Comment: @IndianaJones -- I don't know if you understand fully -- the computer does *exactly* what you tell it to do.  It doesn't say "the output will look nice with spaces, so I'll put them in".  You have to write the code to do what you want, and write it correctly.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie it was my mistake finding the position of c by using float.

Comment: No, using `float` here has nothing to do with the problem. `float` can exactly represent all of the values involved here. Still, it would be better to use an integer type rather than `float`.

Comment: @PeteBecker yes I tested with both solutions mention in 2 answers to the question and both are working fine. The first answer solution with type string and the second answer solution with with size_t

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`' '` is not part `key`.

To handle `c` not found in `key` and remain unchanged, add an `else` statement.

```
    float position = alphabet.find(c);
    if(position != string::npos) {
        char new_char {key.at(position)};
        encrypted_message += new_char;
    } else  // add
        encrypted_message += c;
    }
```

---

Recommend using type `size_type` as that is the type returned by `.find()` and used by `.at()`.

```
    // float position = alphabet.find(c);
    std::string::size_type position = alphabet.find(c);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Float** position = alphabet.find(c); //float is not making errors reading/printing the full line catch, but recommended you use an integer type instead.

**Fix**

**size_t** position = alphabet.find(c); //size_t fixed your issue an un-initialized int and You also forget to complete your if statement in the end by adding the function to set the position of encrypted_message to c as you assigned to be:

**else
encrypted_message += c;**

```
for (char c: secret_message)
    {
    size_t position = alphabet.find(c); 
    if(position != string::npos) {
        char new_char {key.at(position)};
        encrypted_message += new_char;
    } else
        encrypted_message += c;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, it's better to use an integer type rather than `float` here. But the use of `float` is not the problem; `float` can exactly represent all of the values involved here.

Comment: @PeteBecker and Actually he missed to add function to set the position of  encrypted_message to c in the end of if statement.

Comment: @PeteBecker Thank you for making it more clear to understand )